# Unity3d - Jump in collision function

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I want my character to jump only when he's standing on the ground. Despite I wrote the collision function he doesn't jump when I press the key. What is the problem?

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.collider.tag == "groundTag")
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, Jumpforce));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnCollisionEnter2D will only run when it collides with the ground(single frame). probably you need to create a bool for this condition. this may not be the best option. make it true when it collides with ground and make it false when it exits the ground. Write your code in the update function then.

```
    bool _canJump;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, Jumpforce));
    }
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{

    if (col.collider.tag == "groundTag")
    {
        _canJump = true;
    }

}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.collider.tag == "groundTag")
    {
        _canJump = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering your action only when you **enter** the ground trigger (the function you are implementing is `OnCollisionEnter2D`). Your function only works if you are pressing the space key on the same frame the collider collides with a `groundTag` object.

You could try with `OnCollisionStay2D` or use a [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html); that should make implementing the character a bit easier.